# WPF MVVM and remote API - offline mode

Tags: c#, mvvm, synchronization, mvvm-light, offline

I'm working on a WPF app with MVVM pattern (using the Galasoft MVVMLight library). My app loads data from remote API (server) by parsing JSON data to DataModels (using the RestSharp library and the Newtosnoft Json.NET). I need to allow users to modify data from APP (all CRUD operations) directly from app, but my app needs to be responsive also in offline mode and also in environments with slow internet connection.

Now I have it implemented using my DataController class which is registered to different messages generated by my ViewModels (for messaging I'm using the MVVMLight Messenger). So after user for example changes entity A, I send a RequestToUpdate message, DataController handles it and: 1) Update the DataModel assigned with entity A, 
2) Sends message UpdateComplete (so all ViewModels which have this Entity A handles this message and updates ViewModels and Views assigned with this Entity A), 
3) DataController tries to asynchronously update entity on the remote API (every DataModel has a DateTime? property  SyncedToServer, so if remote request fails - user is in offline mode, I set this property to null, otherwise I set it to time of completed sync).

After app is back online, it traverses over all DataModels and checks if they are SyncedToServer and if not, it tries to resync it.

Is there any better pattern/library to implement my app to be responsive and reliable  in offline and bad-internet environments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the requirements for your project but I would consider using  **MSMQ** and **WCF** for this case.

Look at this example
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960174(v=vs.110).aspx

Best ragards
Burim Hajrizaj